# Do line level circuits need shielded enclosures?

Tags: audio

I made a quick volume pedal, just a button, 50k pot, input and output jacks

I used a plastic enclosure for it since it was convenient, but I realized almost all guitar pedals and other stomp boxes are metal. Not only does this help with durability, but it acts as a Faraday cage. Connected to ground, it reduces noise, just like a shielded cable. Is this necessary? I can line the inside with aluminum foil, but it would be annoying to do so, and not sure if it's necessary.

Moreover, I am curious about what is the best practice here.

Does a line level circuit like a volume pedal need a shielded enclosure? (I don't plan on ever using this for something pickup level also.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does a line level circuit like a volume pedal need a shielded enclosure?

No, But if you put your cell phone right next to a plastic box with a high impedance signal loop, poorly designed on the high impedance input, you might be able to pickup the tower re-sync transmissions. dah-dit-da-dit...  This RF often comes from input diode carrier demodulation to baseband and can be suppressed with an RF shunt cap.

Most poor SNR situations come in from radiated noise induced into conducted noise on the signal cables and from poor HF ripple on floating DC supplies.

This current transfers into a voltage from unbalanced impedances for signal and return.

A range of supply capacitors for DC ought to be included from 0.01uF to 10uF to suppress AC hum to RF induced noise currents.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just a hobbyist at best, but you mentioned lining the inside with aluminum foil, and I have done this before.  It wasn't a volume pedal, but it was cheap little stereo.   It was about as cheap as they come: it probably came from a drug store and sold for about US $20 (about 15 years ago). And this thing wasn't just inexpensive (which doesn't necessarily mean low quality), but this thing was CHEAP! It had an FM radio that sported a digital readout of the station it was tuned to, which was purely for looks, After opening it, I saw that it was just and old style mechanical tuner! I can't say if that technology was bad in general, but this thing was. Anyway, it's not surprising that it had an annoying hum coming out of the speakers. So I decided to shield the enclosure from the inside like you mentioned. I didn't use aluminum foil, but I used adhesive backed foil tape which is fairly common (used for duct work maybe?)  You're right, that can be a tedious task, I think I spent a good week or two on the project. The metal can't be soldered, which meant mechanical connections throughout! The CD player was broken, so I had line inputs free, so I gave it 1/4" jacks for guitar/musical gear. It turned out that a soup can was the exact height for the enclosure so that was what the jacks were mounted on! Anyway when I finished the project, I was totally AMAZED at how drastic the reduction in hum was! I really thought I had killed the thing when I first powered it up because at Vol=10 I couldn't hear anything. There of course, was some, but by comparison it was silent.  I wouldn't spend so much time doing that again, but it was an extremely helpful learning experience.  I would say that if you're not noticing any hum, don't bother with shielding it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a high impedance single ended input, which is extremely susceptible to noise. This noise will typically appear as hum.  The wire and or case is actually an antenna which in its own right is very good at low frequencies. Watch out for ground loops they are hard to find and can be very nasty.

This is one of the major reasons the professionals went to balanced inputs typically 600 ohm instead of approximately 10K on a line input. The balanced mode puts the noise in common mode and basically eliminates it.

Consider when doing your design keeping it at the signal source using as little signal line as possible and use a remote to change it. This can be wired or wireless both will work.

In a home environment you may not notice it but it will be there.

For more information look on the Rane web site they post a lot of great information. Start Here: https://www.rane.com/library.html#gpm1_2

I have been playing with this stuff both as a hobby and as a professional for over 60 years.